# How to read several variables from multiple netCDF file to plot a time-series

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, netcdf, python-xarray

I have around 530 netCDF files in a directory, which is essentially monthly data on sea ice ranging from November-1978 to December-2022. I want to plot a time series plot where the y-axis will be `cdr_seaice_conc_monthly` values of a particular latitude and longitude and the x-axis will be the time.

Therefore, I decided to read `time`,`xgrid`, `ygrid`, `cdr_seaice_conc_monthly` variables from all the neCDF files using the following code:

```
import os
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

directory = r'E:\Southern Hemisphere'

file_names = [os.path.join(directory, file) for file in os.listdir(directory) if file.endswith('.nc')]

variables = ['time', 'xgrid', 'ygrid', 'cdr_seaice_conc_monthly']

data_arrays = []

for file_name in file_names:
    
    dataset = xr.open_dataset(file_name)
 
    for variable in variables:
        data_array = dataset[variable]
        data_arrays.append(data_array)
    
    dataset.close()

combined_data = xr.concat(data_arrays, dim='time')

latitude = -70  
longitude = -90  

data_at_location = combined_data.sel(xgrid=longitude, ygrid=latitude, method='nearest')

seaice_conc = data_at_location['cdr_seaice_conc_monthly']

time = data_at_location['time']

plt.plot(time, seaice_conc)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Sea Ice Concentration')
plt.title('Time Series of Sea Ice Concentration')
plt.show()
```

However, I end up with the `ValueError: time already exists as coordinate or variable name`. I believe I am unable to read the files even before reaching the plotting part. Here is the full traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 31
     28     dataset.close()
     30 # Combine the data arrays along the 'time' dimension
---> 31 combined_data = xr.concat(data_arrays, dim='time')
     33 # Extract latitude and longitude of interest
     34 latitude = 0  # Replace with the latitude of interest

File E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\concat.py:231, in concat(objs, dim, data_vars, coords, compat, positions, fill_value, join, combine_attrs)
    226     raise ValueError(
    227         f"compat={compat!r} invalid: must be 'broadcast_equals', 'equals', 'identical', 'no_conflicts' or 'override'"
    228     )
    230 if isinstance(first_obj, DataArray):
--> 231     return _dataarray_concat(
    232         objs,
    233         dim=dim,
    234         data_vars=data_vars,
    235         coords=coords,
    236         compat=compat,
    237         positions=positions,
    238         fill_value=fill_value,
    239         join=join,
    240         combine_attrs=combine_attrs,
    241     )
    242 elif isinstance(first_obj, Dataset):
    243     return _dataset_concat(
    244         objs,
    245         dim=dim,
   (...)
    252         combine_attrs=combine_attrs,
    253     )

File E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\concat.py:657, in _dataarray_concat(arrays, dim, data_vars, coords, compat, positions, fill_value, join, combine_attrs)
    654             arr = cast(T_DataArray, arr.rename(name))
    655     datasets.append(arr._to_temp_dataset())
--> 657 ds = _dataset_concat(
    658     datasets,
    659     dim,
    660     data_vars,
    661     coords,
    662     compat,
    663     positions,
    664     fill_value=fill_value,
    665     join=join,
    666     combine_attrs=combine_attrs,
    667 )
    669 merged_attrs = merge_attrs([da.attrs for da in arrays], combine_attrs)
    671 result = arrays[0]._from_temp_dataset(ds, name)

File E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\concat.py:485, in _dataset_concat(datasets, dim, data_vars, coords, compat, positions, fill_value, join, combine_attrs)
    482 # case where concat dimension is a coordinate or data_var but not a dimension
    483 if (dim in coord_names or dim in data_names) and dim not in dim_names:
    484     # TODO: Overriding type because .expand_dims has incorrect typing:
--> 485     datasets = [cast(T_Dataset, ds.expand_dims(dim)) for ds in datasets]
    487 # determine which variables to concatenate
    488 concat_over, equals, concat_dim_lengths = _calc_concat_over(
    489     datasets, dim, dim_names, data_vars, coords, compat
    490 )

File E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\concat.py:485, in <listcomp>(.0)
    482 # case where concat dimension is a coordinate or data_var but not a dimension
    483 if (dim in coord_names or dim in data_names) and dim not in dim_names:
    484     # TODO: Overriding type because .expand_dims has incorrect typing:
--> 485     datasets = [cast(T_Dataset, ds.expand_dims(dim)) for ds in datasets]
    487 # determine which variables to concatenate
    488 concat_over, equals, concat_dim_lengths = _calc_concat_over(
    489     datasets, dim, dim_names, data_vars, coords, compat
    490 )

File E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataset.py:3915, in Dataset.expand_dims(self, dim, axis, **dim_kwargs)
   3913         raise ValueError(f"Dimension {d} already exists.")
   3914     if d in self._variables and not utils.is_scalar(self._variables[d]):
-> 3915         raise ValueError(
   3916             "{dim} already exists as coordinate or"
   3917             " variable name.".format(dim=d)
   3918         )
   3920 variables: dict[Hashable, Variable] = {}
   3921 indexes: dict[Hashable, Index] = dict(self._indexes)

ValueError: time already exists as coordinate or variable name.
```

The dataset contains the following variables:

```
cdr_seaice_conc_monthly           (tdim, y, x) float32 ...
    nsidc_bt_seaice_conc_monthly      (tdim, y, x) float32 ...
    nsidc_nt_seaice_conc_monthly      (tdim, y, x) float32 ...
    projection                        |S1 ...
    qa_of_cdr_seaice_conc_monthly     (tdim, y, x) float32 ...
    stdev_of_cdr_seaice_conc_monthly  (tdim, y, x) float32 ...
```

These are the attributes if it is useful:

```
Attributes:
    long_name:            NOAA/NSIDC Climate Data Record of Passive Microwave...
    standard_name:        sea_ice_area_fraction
    units:                1
    flag_values:          [251 252 253 254 255]
    flag_meanings:        pole_hole lakes coastal land_mask missing_data
    datum:                +ellps=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326
    grid_mapping:         projection
    reference:            https://nsidc.org/data/g02202/versions/4/
    ancillary_variables:  stdev_of_cdr_seaice_conc_monthly qa_of_cdr_seaice_c...
    valid_range:          [  0 100], 'nsidc_bt_seaice_conc_monthly': <xarray.Variable (tdim: 1, y: 332, x: 316)>
[104912 values with dtype=float32]
Attributes:
    long_name:      Passive Microwave Monthly Southern Hemisphere Sea Ice Con...
    standard_name:  sea_ice_area_fraction
    units:          1
    flag_values:    [251 252 253 254 255]
    flag_meanings:  pole_hole unused coastal land_mask missing_data
    datum:          +ellps=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326
    grid_mapping:   projection
    valid_range:    [  0 100], 'nsidc_nt_seaice_conc_monthly': <xarray.Variable (tdim: 1, y: 332, x: 316)>
[104912 values with dtype=float32]
Attributes:
    long_name:      Passive Microwave Monthly Southern Hemisphere Sea Ice Con...
    standard_name:  sea_ice_area_fraction
    units:          1
    flag_values:    [251 252 253 254 255]
    flag_meanings:  pole_hole unused coastal land_mask missing_data
    datum:          +ellps=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326
    grid_mapping:   projection
    valid_range:    [  0 100], 'projection': <xarray.Variable ()>
[1 values with dtype=|S1]
Attributes: (12/23)
    grid_boundary_top_projected_y:          4350000.0
    grid_boundary_bottom_projected_y:       -3950000.0
    grid_boundary_right_projected_x:        3950000.0
    grid_boundary_left_projected_x:         -3950000.0
    parent_grid_cell_row_subset_start:      0.0
    parent_grid_cell_row_subset_end:        332.0
    ...                                     ...
    scaling_factor:                         1.0
    false_easting:                          0.0
    false_northing:                         0.0
    semimajor_radius:                       6378273.0
    semiminor_radius:                       6356889.449
    units:                                  meters, 'qa_of_cdr_seaice_conc_monthly': <xarray.Variable (tdim: 1, y: 332, x: 316)>
[104912 values with dtype=float32]
Attributes:
    long_name:      Passive Microwave Monthly Southern Hemisphere Sea Ice Con...
    standard_name:  sea_ice_area_fraction status_flag
    flag_meanings:  Average_concentration_exceeds_0.15 Average_concentration_...
    datum:          +ellps=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326
    grid_mapping:   projection
    flag_masks:     [  1   2   4   8  32  64 128]
    valid_range:    [  1 255], 'stdev_of_cdr_seaice_conc_monthly': <xarray.Variable (tdim: 1, y: 332, x: 316)>
[104912 values with dtype=float32]
Attributes:
    long_name:     Passive Microwave Monthly Southern Hemisphere Sea Ice Conc...
    datum:         +ellps=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326
    grid_mapping:  projection
    valid_range:   [0. 1.], 'time': <xarray.Variable (tdim: 1)>
[1 values with dtype=datetime64[ns]]
Attributes:
    standard_name:  time
    long_name:      ANSI date
    axis:           T, 'xgrid': <xarray.Variable (x: 316)>
array([-3937500., -3912500., -3887500., ...,  3887500.,  3912500.,  3937500.],
      dtype=float32)
Attributes:
    valid_range:    [-3950000.  3950000.]
    units:          meters
    long_name:      projection_grid_x_centers
    standard_name:  projection_x_coordinate
    axis:           X, 'ygrid': <xarray.Variable (y: 332)>
array([ 4337500.,  4312500.,  4287500., ..., -3887500., -3912500., -3937500.],
      dtype=float32)
Attributes:
    valid_range:    [-3950000.  4350000.]
    units:          meters
    long_name:      projection_grid_y_centers
    standard_name:  projection_y_coordinate
    axis:           Y}))
```

I am also adding a link to one of the sample files of last two years for convenience:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cisCaOynpVF8b-oGU1J7QcjkNGvpvtRV?usp=sharing

I will be immensely grateful if anyone is able to provide me with a solution to this or suggest any alternative ways to achieve this. Thank you once again for taking the time to read.

Comment: Could you provide a link to a file sample in order to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @jlandercy Thanks for taking the time to respond. I have edited the question and added a link to one of the netCDF files, I hope you will find it useful.

Comment: @asheef_ik, I clicked the link, it shows "The transfer you requested has been deleted."

Comment: @BoHuang I am sorry for the inconvenience, I uploaded the sample file to google drive instead. Can you please check again?

Comment: I converted it to a pandas dataframe and concated. Then work from pandas. Don't know if that's a viable option. see [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Kaf.png)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thank you for your suggestions, with your help I was able to read all the variables of the netCDF files. However, whenever I want to plot a time series I get an empty plot, is it okay if I ask you to take a look at the notebook? Here is the link to it: https://nbviewer.org/github/Asheef1447/Antarctic-Sea-Ice-Plot-in-Python/blob/main/Multi_nc_timeseries.ipynb

Comment: If you look at the values in `xgrid` and `ygrid`, they are not in the range of `latitude_range = (-80, -70)` and `longitude_range = (-135, -180)`, so `filtered_df` is empty. `xgrid` and `ygrid` don't appear to be longitude and latitude.

Comment: Just do `ax = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='time', y='cdr_seaice_conc_monthly', s=1,figsize=(8, 15))`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney sorry to bother you again but I am getting a figure like after using the code you provided, this is the updated notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QN3aZr_wt1zWnssz6tWUiUKm8wqLsikO?usp=sharing

Comment: There was an issue in this line `ds = xr.open_dataset(file_name)[variables]` this is the updated line.  The previous line had `file_names[0]` so you were only loading the first file multiple times.

Comment: Thank you, I followed your instructions and obtained the following figure: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/147aNwQ5JLTHWDfamVEvWi87C9P90FgfQ?usp=sharing . Do I need to regrid my latitude or longitude or assign projections in order to get a time series plot of specific latitude and longitude?